# Account deletion

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, linked-accounts

If I follow the instructions given [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account), will this only delete the association of my account with SO, or will it remove my entire network profile, including my account on, say, stats.SE?

Comment: quote from the [faq entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/186381): Either of these procedures cover deleting your account on **one specific site**.

Comment: @Servy Thanks. Just wanted to double check since account deletion is permanent.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it will just delete your data from that one Site which you want to be deleted! Other sites won't be disturbed.